# Is there any place for teleology in physics?

Tags: cosmology, causality

Most physicists absolutely hate the idea of [teleology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleology). They take it as an unquestionable article of faith that causality only runs in one direction, that is, from the past to the future.

Is there any room for teleology in physics? What's so wrong with teleology? Why can't events be at least partially caused by some future goal?

I'm looking for some sort of technical analysis, not opinion based.

Comment: This is some kind of teleology: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action

Comment: More on teleology: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=teleology

Comment: according to the definition in your link the increase in entropy second law of thermodynamics sounds teleological to me.

Comment: I like the fork example at the top of Wikipedia. We could also talk about teleology in evolved body parts, in some sense. (Wings had an intermediate "purpose" which was not flying.) But here's the important issue for me: **Can you design crucial experiments proving one view or another about teleology correct?** If you can design such an experiment whose conclusion convinces basically all comers, then the teleology debate could be like ideal science.